# How can I get from this dataframe to a dictionary in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

In Python, how do I get from the following [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeMXG.png)

...to one of the following dictionary structures in the most efficient ways?

[Dictionary structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnCAz.png)

[Dictionary structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dhZV.png)

Thanks a lot for your support!

Best regards,

Dennis

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.